# What are the contents need to add in hteader.html from index.html?

Tags: css, html

I have created simple web page using `HTML5`, `CSS` and `jQuery`.

Here is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Responsive Design Website</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "css/style.css"  media="screen"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/animatecss/2.1.0/animate.min.css">
    <link href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,800" rel="stylesheet" />           
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="engine1/style.css" />
    <link href="video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico">
    <script src="video.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
    videojs.options.flash.swf = "video-js.swf";
    </script>
  </head>
  <body id="demo-one">
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

    <div id = "wrap">
<header>
----
</header>
<!--Here slideshow-->
<aside>
------
</aside>
<!---Main content-->
<footer>
------
</footer>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now i want to know basic knowledge about, What are the contents that need to add in header.html and footer.html from index.html file?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: actually what's your requirement

Comment: ok main three page , main index.php ,and included in indesx.php two page , 1) header page , 2) footer.php

Comment: your all header content in header.php and this header page include in index.php

Comment: What header.html and footer.html? You probably want to know how to organize your site so that all pages share the same header and footer, using some inclusion mechanism. This is a design issue and off-topic at SO. But as asked, the question really falls into the category “unclear what you are asking”.

Answer (score 0):

**In header.html**

```
logo
menu
```

**In footer.html**

```
social icon
copy rights
```

Answer (score -1):

all of this needs to go in the header.html

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Responsive Design Website</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "css/style.css"  media="screen"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/animatecss/2.1.0/animate.min.css">
    <link href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,800" rel="stylesheet" />           
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="engine1/style.css" />
    <link href="video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico">

  </head>
</html>
```

And this goes in the footer.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<footer>
<script src="video.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
    videojs.options.flash.swf = "video-js.swf";
    </script>
</footer>
</html>
```

Comment: ok main three page , main index.php ,and included in indesx.php two page , 1) header page , 2) footer.php

Comment: then after add all pages header.php  and footer.php

Comment: yes, like all html pages, you need to start with <!DOCTYPE html>
<html> and finish with </html>

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?php include("header.html");?>
</html>

Comment: If they are to be used via some include mechanism, it is definitely incorrect to have `DOCTYPE` and `<html>` in both of them.

Comment: There is no exact question (well, no *real* question in SO terms).