# Issue in header,footer and index.html in HTML5

Tags: css, html

I have created small web page using HTML5,CSS3 and jQuery.

Here is my code for index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
   <?php include("header.html");?>
  <body id="demo-one">
   <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
      <div id = "wrap">
      <!-- Header --> 
      <header>
      <div id="address">255 Nandanam,  linefocus CT 06810 | + 044 - 4386 1111 | <a href="mailto:info@linefocus.com" class="white">info@linefocus.com</a></div>
        <div id="logo"><img class="header-image" src="img/Untitled-1.png" alt="Church Of Our Lady Of Health - Pattabiram Military Siding" />
        <h5 class="caption">Church Of Our Lady Of Health - Pattabiram Military Siding</h5>
          </div>
                  <!-- Search box --> 
        <form>
          <input type="search" placeholder="Search">
        </form>
          <!-- End Search box --> 
                          <!-- Navigation --> 
        <nav id="menu-wrap">
        </nav>

        <!-- End Navigation -->

      </header>

        <!-- End Header --> 
             <!--main-->
<main class="clearfix"> 
<aside class="sidebar">
<div class="inside">
<section id="content">
</section>
        </div>
            <!-- Youtube palyer-1 -->

    <div class="inside">
    <section class="content">

    </section>
    </div>
                <!-- Youtube palyer-2 -->

    <div class="inside">
    <section class="content">

    </section>
    </div>
            <!-- Facebook Page -->

        <div class="inside">
    <section class="content">
   </section>
    </div>
        <!-- News Feed -->
        <div class="inside">
    <section class="content">

   </section>
   </div>
    </aside>
<!--main content-->

<!--end main--> 
 <!-- #footer -->
 <?php include("footer.html");?>    
<!-- / #footer -->
   </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='http://codepen.io/assets/libs/fullpage/jquery.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/wowslider.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/script.js"></script>
<!--js--sticky-footer--> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/menu.js"></script>
  <script src="js/index-scroll.js"></script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

This is header.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Responsive Design Website</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "css/style.css"  media="screen"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/animatecss/2.1.0/animate.min.css">
    <link href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,800" rel="stylesheet" />           
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="engine1/style.css" />
    <link href="video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico">
    <script src="video.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
    videojs.options.flash.swf = "video-js.swf";
    </script>
  </head>
  </html>
```

footer.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
        <!-- #footer > #links-home -->
        <footer>

        <address itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
        <span class="copyright">Copyright © 2014</span>&nbsp;
        <span class="name" itemprop="legalName"> Church Of Our Lady Of Health.</span>
    </address>
    </footer>
</html>
```

But my web page didn't contain any styles or nothing. page looks like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/5i14L.jpg

I think my codes are incorrect, may i know, what are the methods or what are exact contents need to apply in my header.html and footer.html from my index.html?

can anyone Please help me to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you get any error in console??

Comment: You're using PHP code in your html file??? Your files should be of `.php` extension...

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai: how do i know error console?

Comment: for include purpose using php, otherwise html file only @Xlander

Comment: @deepika Using f12  you can check it in chrome browser

Comment: But you *index* file is an **html** file when it should have been a **php** file. And also, there should only have one `<!DOCTYPE HTML>`, `<html>` and `<body>` tag in the overall page.

Comment: when i pres f12, it shows like this http://imgur.com/P2ll2IF @SureshPonnukalai

Comment: @Xlander: can you provide me answer from my posted question?

Comment: @deepika look at your f12 image. It have 8 errors. Click on that it will explain what are the issues. Hopefully your js and CSS not loaded properly. Oh my god, Are you checking this site with internet access or locally??

Comment: Can you click on *Console*? Then I may figure it out.

Comment: This is just a repost of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26645344/what-are-the-contents-need-to-add-in-hteader-html-from-index-html and not really any better than it.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doint same

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
```

In all you partial views?

Make something like this

**This is header.html:**

```
<head>
    <title>Responsive Design Website</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "css/style.css"  media="screen"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/animatecss/2.1.0/animate.min.css">
    <link href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,800" rel="stylesheet" />           
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="engine1/style.css" />
    <link href="video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico">
    <script src="video.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
    videojs.options.flash.swf = "video-js.swf";
    </script>
  </head>
```

**And this is footer.html**

```
  <!-- #footer > #links-home -->
        <footer>

        <address itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
        <span class="copyright">Copyright © 2014</span>&nbsp;
        <span class="name" itemprop="legalName"> Church Of Our Lady Of Health.</span>
    </address>
    </footer>
```